# Changing Header Height of Stack Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have been trying to change the height of my stack navigator header. However, nothing is working!

```
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="LiveLandingScreen">
      <Stack.Screen name="LiveLandingScreen" component={LiveLandingScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="History" component={History} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

the code is working fine but could anyone help me with changing the header height, please?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is doing this, if we suppose you want to change the height of header bar for History you will do :

```
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="LiveLandingScreen">
      <Stack.Screen name="LiveLandingScreen" component={LiveLandingScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="History" component={History} option={{headerStyle: {height: 60}}} />.  ///ADD OPTION
</Stack.Navigator>
```

I hope it helps <3

Comment: I just tried it out and it is not working. Do I have to import a certain library for te option prop to work?

Comment: no there is nothing needed for that,,, its one of the props of stack.screen!

Comment: happy to hear that , mutlu kodlamalar <3

Comment: I also cannot see anything changing with different values for the heading (Android). I have added the height to the screenOptions and also to the individual screen options attribute (Note documentation says options, not option. Anyhow I was hoping the background color would stop extending to the top! :)

Comment: can you share the version you are using and a gist file to your stacks? @gfmoore

Comment: v6. I'll probably use a custom header once I figure out how :)

Comment: did you check this out ?
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options @gfmoore

Comment: does not work on v6